# Replacing link in a href tag by php

Tags: php, replace, preg-replace, str-replace

I have links like

```
<a href="#GGGGGGG31321">LINK TEXT</a>
<a href="#zzzz313GG31321">LINK TEXT 2</a>
```

...

ATTENTION! # symbol in begin is important, because i have and another links what i dont want to change

how i can replace by php it  to:

```
<a href="#">LINK TEXT</a>
<a href="#">LINK TEXT 2</a>
```

Or better how i can leave link text, but remove a href tags fully

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

try this regex

```
 <?php
    $vv='<a href="#GGGGGGG31321">LINK TEXT</a>
    <a href="#zzzz313GG31321">LINK TEXT 2</a>';
    $vv=preg_replace('/<a(.*)href="([^"]*)"(.*)>/','<a$1href="#"$3>',$vv);
    echo $vv;
 ?>
```

test & work

Comment: # symbol is important for me

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work:

```
preg_replace( '/<a\shref=\".*\">(.+<\/a>)/', '<a>$1', $linkTag );
```

It should remove the whole `href` tag.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $string = '<a href="#GGGGGGG31321">LINK TEXT</a><a href="#zzzz313GG31321">LINK TEXT 2</a>';
    $regex = '/<a\\shref=".*?">(.*?)<\\/a>/is';
    echo preg_replace($regex, '<a>$1</a>', $string);
?>
```

This returns:
    `<a>LINK TEXT</a>`

Maybe I didn't understand you when you said

> Or better how i can leave link text, but remove a href tags fully

but hopefully it's helpful.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
preg_replace('/\bhref="#[^"]+"/', 'href="#"', $string)
```